# Count values in dict of pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, count

I have a pandas series of dicts like this:

```
print(df['genres'])
0                        {'0': '1', '1': '4', '2': '23'}
1             {'0': '1', '1': '25', '2': '4', '3': '37'}
2                                             {'0': '9'}

print(type(df['genres']))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

print(type(df['genres'][0]))
<class 'dict'>
```

I want to count the values to get something like this:

```
{'1': 2, '4': 2, '9': 1, '23': 1, '25': 1, '37': 1}
```

I tried the following:

```
print(Counter(chain.from_iterable(df.genres.values)))
Counter({'0': 3, '1': 2, '2': 2, '3': 1})

print(pd.Series(df['genres']).value_counts())
{'0': '1', '1': '4', '2': '23'}                                  1
{'0': '1', '1': '25', '2': '4', '3': '37'}                       1
{'0': '9'}                                                       1
```

I think it is pretty easy for someone more experienced than me. But I really don't get it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
pd.DataFrame(list(df.genres)).stack().value_counts().to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{'1': 2, '4': 2, '37': 1, '9': 1, '23': 1, '25': 1}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried and get an error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_list'